# Writable selectInput selectors

Tags: css, r, shiny

I want to modify my selectInput in such a way that it is 'writable'. For instance, 'location' contains Amsterdam, Rotterdam, Den Haag, etc. I want to implement an inputselector which is 'writable'. So when somebody writes "Ams.." or "Amster..." is shows the possible locations which match this criteria. 
Can somebody please help me? Thank you in advance.

This is my simplified **ui** section:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

Location = c("Amsterdam","Amsterdam","Amsterdam","Rotterdam","Rotterdam","Rotterdam","Den Haag","Den Haag","Den Haag") 
Year = c(2015,2014,2016,2015,2016,2016,2017,2016,2014) 
Person = c("John", "Ann", "Katy", "Ann", "Katy", "William", "Henry", "Luke", "Luke")
mockup = data.frame(Location, Year, Person)

ui <- dashboardPage(
                    dashboardHeader(),
                    dashboardSidebar(
                      sidebarMenu(
                        menuItem("Selection", tabName = "selection")                  
                                  )
                    ),
                    dashboardBody(
                      tabItems(
                        tabItem(tabName = "selection",
                                fluidRow(
                                  box(width = 5, 
                                      title = "TITLE", "Choose something",
                                      collapsible = FALSE, 
                                      htmlOutput("Location_selector"),
                                      htmlOutput("Year_selector")
                                  ),
                                  mainPanel(
                                    DT::dataTableOutput("selection")
                                  )
                                 ))             

                                        )
                      )
                      )
```

and this is my **server** section:

```
    server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$Location_selector = renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "Location",
                label = "Location:",
                choices = sort(as.character(unique(mockup$Location))))
  })
  output$Year_selector = renderUI({

    data_available = mockup[mockup$Location == input$Location, "Year"]

    selectInput(inputId = "Year",
                label = "Year:",
                choices = sort(unique(data_available)),
                selected = unique(data_available)[1])
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question here on SO. I adjusted the 'choices' part of the server section, by adding an empty option (" "):

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$Location_selector = renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "Location",
                label = "Location:",
                choices = c("", (sort(as.character(unique(mockup$Location))))))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```